# RAII or 'finally' emulation in bash

Tags: bash, raii, finally

I'm looking for best practice for emulating RAII or 'finally' in a **function** in bash.

Using the trap mechanism is acceptable, but then it must all happen in a subshell.  I am looking for ways to be able to decompose scripts into functions that clean up after themselves.

To give an example, say I want create a directory and mount a file system, poke around while various error conditions can happen.

```
my_func() {
    local mnt=$(mktemp -d)
    $MAGIC 'rmdir $mnt' # RIAA-style cleanup
    mount /dev/disk $mnt
    $MAGIC 'umount $mnt' # another RIAA-style cleanup
    if [ $foo blash ]; then
       echo "Nah, $foo is blash, please blargh!"
       return 1
    fi
    ...
    if [ ! -f $mnt/file ]; then
       echo "File does not exist, blargh!"
       return 1
    fi
    ...
    if ! grep -q 'blargh!!!' $mnt/file; then
       echo "Blargh!!! not found, blargh!"
       return 1
    fi
    ...
    echo "Success, nice!"
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for `trap`, e.g.

```
trap "rmdir $mnt" EXIT
```